# Solr Facet Search - Get Value based on Max and Group by

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to get the price based on the maximum timestamp grouped by source.

The Solr query i have right now pulls the maximum timestamp for each source. How can I modify this query to pull the corresponding price associated with the maximum timestamp?

```
http://localhost:6500/solr/listings/select?q=desc_t:"Watch"&indent=on&rows=0&indent=true&wt=json&json.facet=
{
    prices: {
        type: terms,
        field: source_s,
        facet: {
            max_ingestdate: "max(timestamp_dt)"                   
                }

            }
        }
```

This returns back:

```
"facets":{
    "count":141211,
    "prices":{
      "buckets":[{
          "val":"a1",
          "count":71466,
          "max_ingestdate":1.505277283278E12},
        {
          "val":"a2",
          "count":52415,
          "max_ingestdate":1.501872553356E12},
        {
          "val":"a3",
          "count":7866,
          "max_ingestdate":1.504798294686E12},....
```

I also want the corressponding price so the final result should be:

```
"facets":{
"count":141211,
"prices":{
  "buckets":[{
      "val":"a1",
      "count":71466,
      "max_ingestdate":1.505277283278E12,
      "price": 1334},
    {
      "val":"a2",
      "count":52415,
      "max_ingestdate":1.501872553356E12,
      "price": 1234},
    {
      "val":"a3",
      "count":7866,
      "max_ingestdate":1.504798294686E12
      "price": 1342},...
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure it is possible to just grab one document within a json facet but here is a semi-hack you could use if you just wanted to use the most recent price. Essentially you could facet by source, as you are doing, and then within that source facet use a query facet on price in a series of short time windows.

The solr call would look something like:

```
http://localhost:65000/solr/listings/select?q=description_t:"Watch"&indent=on&rows=0&indent=true&wt=json&json.facet=
    {
        prices: {
            type: terms,
            field: source_s,
            facet: {
                max_ingestdate: "max(timestamp_dt)",
                max_price: "max(price_d)",
                price_1: {
                    type: query,
                    q: "timestamp_dt:[NOW-1DAY TO NOW]",
                    facet: {
                        avg_price_1: "avg(price_d)"
                    }
                },
                price_2: {
                    type: query,
                    q: "timestamp_dt:[NOW-7DAY TO NOW-1DAY]",
                    facet: {
                        avg_price_2: "avg(price_d)"
                    }
                },
                price_3: {
                    type: query,
                    q: "timestamp_dt:[NOW-14DAY TO NOW-7DAY]",
                    facet: {
                        avg_price_3: "avg(price_d)"
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes.This looks like the best possible solution so far.